# wait for event dispatcher to finish in Flex

Tags: events, flex4

I am newbie to Flex.
I want to fire2 events event 1 and event 2 like
dispatcher( event 1);
dispatcher( event 2);

event 2 was fire before event 1 has finished. How can i make event 2 to wait for event 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be two stratergies:

1: Make your structure so that , you would fire event 2 in the event handler for event 1.
2: In the hanlder for event 2, check for the value of a global variable, lets say its just a boolean, if its true, then go ahead with event2 handler work and set the boolean to false,and if its false, recursively call the hanlder using a setTimeout.
In the handler for event 1, set this boolean to true.
This is a very crude implementation of mutex and will allow serialization between only two events.